# Control how to create divs in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to click anywhere on the screen and a div(called #note) will show up. I am able to create as many #notes as I want, but I don't want to click on #note and have another div appear.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#wrp').click(function () {
    var note = $('#note').first();
    note.clone().insertBefore(note);
    console.log(note);
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: That would create many divs with ID `#note`, which is invalid html. Also, what is `#wrp`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain very well!

Comment: I know, I originally had #note as .note, but i changed it to #note to see if that would fix my problem

Comment: #wrp is the wrapper that covers the whole screen, so clicking anywhere on it will create     #note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the target of the click using the event target. Then use `closest()` to see if it is a note element itself, or one of it's descendents that was clicked

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    // only proceed if clcik is not anywhere in a note element
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.note').length) {    
        var note = $('.note').first();
        note.clone().insertBefore(note);
        console.log(note);
    }
});
```

Using `class="note"` to avoid duplicate ID's